# DropBox Datastore Xamarin component for Android

Tags: c#, android, dropbox, xamarin, datastore

I am starting out with Xamarin writing Android apps. I found DropBox'x DataStore component for Xamarin very interesting and I believe it would suite my needs if it only worked with Android Xamarin. Currently the component (Dropbox.IOS.dll) targets IOS only. I'm wondering if someone has already converted this component for Xamarin Android use.